# Observable doesn't load data on router change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

working with Angular (v7.2) and Firebase Auth to build a simple web app with a members area. I've set the dashboard up in a separate module with its own router. I've got a service which does most of the heavy lifting for the auth which is shared between all the components.

I'm not convinced this is the best way of doing things but my auth.service.ts file looks like this:

```
export class AuthService {
   private userData$ = new Subject();
   private userData;
   public userDataObs = this.userData$.asObservable();

   constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public functions: AngularFireFunctions, public router: Router, public ngZone: NgZone) {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
       if(user) {
         this.userData = user;

         this.getCurrentUserAccessLevel().subscribe((result) => {
           let userAccessLevel = result.result;
           let userObj = {
             displayName: this.userData.displayName,
             email: this.userData.email,
             emailVerified: this.userData.emailVerified,
             phoneNumber: this.userData.phoneNumber,
             photoURL: this.userData.photoURL,
             uid: this.userData.uid,
             accessLevel: userAccessLevel
           }

           this.userData$.next(userObj);
         });

         localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
         JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
       } else {
         localStorage.setItem('user', null);
         JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
       }
     })
   }
...
```

In short the service fetches the user data from the Firebase auth service and stores it into a userData property. It then fetches the accessLevel which is a custom claim in Firebase auth and merges this with some fields in the userData to create a custom userObj object. The userObj is then submitted to the userData$ subject for which there is an observable userDataObs.

Each component subscribes to userDataObs.

In the main dashboard.component.ts there is:

```
export class DashboardComponent {

  private userDataObs;
  private userData;
  private loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router, public ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.authService.userDataObs.subscribe((data) => {
      this.userData = data;
      this.loaded = true;
    })
  }

}
```

which simply subscribes to the userDataObs in the authService. In the main dashboard component there is a menu with various routerLinks to other components which are served through a router-outlet in the component. If I click the link to another component the route changes and the component initialises but the observable does not load. There is no error message or anything - just nothing:

dashboard-profile.component.ts:

```
export class DashboardProfileComponent {

  private userDataObs;
  private userData;
  private loaded: boolean = false;
  private fileUploadEvent;
  private fileUploadProgress;
  private fileUploadURL;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private uploadService: UploadService) {
    console.log('constructor');
    this.authService.userDataObs.subscribe((data) => {
      this.userData = data;
      this.loaded = true;
      console.log('loaded');
    });
  }
```

If, however, I just navigate to the route, without clicking the routerLink it works fine.

I assume it's something to do with sharing the observable? Ideally I'd just like the child components to somehow inherit the observable from the dashboard.component but from what I can tell this isn't possible, hence I need to set up a new subscription.

Would appreciate any help at all! Thank you!

Comment: A couple of things to consider. You can use a subject such as a [ReplaySubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) to emit old and new values. Next, don't perform expensive operations such as API calls or similar in constructors of components, instead use ngOnInit().

Comment: ReplaySubject did it, thank you! Didn't know it existed, makes sense now! Have also moved everything into ngOnInit() I actually had it that way before but moved the code to the constructors just for diagnosis